# Swift/Xcode tab bar badge refresh

Tags: swift, xcode, tabbar, badge

Code snippet:

`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2].badgeValue = "999"`

The code above works, but my tab bar badge updates only when I scroll (interact with) the view. Any thoughts?

The badgeValue is updated whenever I add or remove an item from a shopping bag. This function is in the Bag class:

```
func adicionarProduto(idProduto : Int){ 
    produtos.append(idProduto) self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2].badgeValue = String(sacola.produtos.count) 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define in your question where or/and when exactly you try to update the tab bar batch count please.

Comment: Where in the code are you setting the badgeValue?

Comment: The badgeValue is updated whenever I add or remove an item from a shopping bag. This function is in the Bag class:


`func adicionarProduto(idProduto : Int){
        produtos.append(idProduto)
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[2].badgeValue = String(sacola.produtos.count)
    }`